# how to remove single character(letter) from corpus using python

Tags: python

I would like to remove any single characters from each document in corpus.
For example, let's say there are some typos or non-English letters.

```
corpus=['I like this d hotel room because it was clean.','This hotel is very y close to downtown area.']
```

What I've tried was

```
corpus=' '.join( [w for w in corpus.split() if len(w)>1] )
```

but didn't work. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with the code you wrote. Note that `corpus` is a `list` and not `str`

Comment: Even if you get this working, this will filter out `"I"` or `"a"` which are very much words. I think you need a natural language processing library or at least a dictionary lookup to establish word validity. The difference between a typo and an actual word isn't something that can be determined as naively as `len(word) > 1`. What you're asking for could have arbitrarily deep complexity depending on your exact requirements and the nature of the corpus and how you're defining a "typo".

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
corpus = ['I like this d hotel room because it was clean.', 'This hotel is very y close to downtown area.']
corpus1 = []
for entry in corpus:
    corpus1.append(' '.join(x for x in entry.split() if len(x) > 1))
print(corpus1)
```

output

```
['like this hotel room because it was clean.', 'This hotel is very close to downtown area.']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```py
corpus=['I like this d hotel room because it was clean.','This hotel is very y close to downtown area.']
clean_corpus=[]
for sentence in corpus:
    clean_sentence=[]
    parts=sentence.split(" ")
    for part in parts:
        invalid=False
        if (len(part)==1) and (part.lower()!="a") and (part.lower()!="i") and (not part.isdigit()):
            invalid=True
        if not invalid:
            clean_sentence.append(part)
    clean_corpus.append(" ".join(clean_sentence))
print(clean_corpus)
```

This cleans out all single letter words that are not "a", "A", "i", "I", or a digit (1, 2, 3, ...).

Try it yourself and tell me in the comments if it worked or what could be improved!